# Refresh DOM without re-pulling outer includes (fe. JS or CSS) / Refreshing DOM without full site refresh

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How could I refresh the DOM without actually refreshing the page?

I mean, **without** refreshing 'pulled' **includes**, like outer stylesheets, or outer scripts.

Comment: that is ajax doing or iframe

Comment: Look at ajax with javascript to load content and fill the contents of the DOM element. This is all made a lot easier with jQuery and more specifically http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank You for Your suggestions, You are both completely right, but I need a method to actually refresh the whole DOM element not just add contents to the DOM.

Comment: You would replace the DOM contents with ajax. or do you literally mean `window.location = window.location`?

Comment: Not that I could see any reason for why this would be useful, but simply setting the content of the document body to be the content of itself should achieve what your after.

Comment: No, not really. We would lose event listeners, and achieve a very static page ( because it's based on a string storage )
.
But if we won't, then it would be the solution that I am looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it just doesn't make sense. Refreshing the page causes 1) the HTML to be fetched 2) the linked resources like style sheets and scripts to be fetched and 3) the scripts to be executed. It seems like you trying to get at 3) but  in a roundabout way. Just throw away the DOM and re-run the scripts or use something that's designed for it, like React.

Comment: Yeah, something like React sounds like a solution, indeed. Thanks, @Gunchars

Answer (score 0):

Feels kinda ugly but something like this?

```
jQuery("body").html(jQuery("body").html())
```

Native that should be something long the lines of

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
```

Comment: Seems to be logical, but looks horrible. I am pretty sure, that not everything would work properly this way.

For example the document will not proc a ready, or onload again, and also what about the PHP scripts? I am not sure they will work properly this way.

Comment: Agreed - the browser do things on refresh that this would miss out on. Also listeners etc are lost. However if the document have an "initial state" saved somewhere that might be better? For what reason do you need to do this without a full page refresh?

Comment: I need this for a very specific reason. I have to create a really fast 'reload' method basically ON the site, and to make it even faster I would like not to reinclude anything from outer files, just refresh the DOM. 

But the solution would be useful for those who are making PHP-JSON delayed scripting, and also would replace the jQuery delegations.

Comment: So in essence something that: When page is loaded, before page onload is triggered, store the initial HTML for later use. Then at some point later; reinstantiate the body from the initial HTML and re-trigger the events?

Comment: Sure. That is what I am looking for. But without re-including the outer pulled scripts, stylesheets, and such. That's important not to.

Comment: That sounds like a job for a framework, perhaps angular?

Comment: A framework such as React (or Mithril) which already works on a virtual DOM-tree should be a viable solution for quick handling of site-state changes.